# iOS, Use struct in Objective C, struct values not assignable from super view

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct

I am trying to use a struct to store three values as a unit so to speak. I am getting an error: "`Expression not assignable`" when I try to assign values to the struct's values from the object's super view.

Anyone know why this is?

in my class's .h file I have defined the struct and a property

```
@interface MyClass : UIView

{
    struct customStruct {
        float a;
        float b;
        float c;
    };

}

@property (assign, nonatomic) struct customStruct myStruct;
```

from the super view I try to assign a value and I get an error: "`Expression not assignable`"

```
object.myStruct.a = someValue;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct customStruct aStruct = object.myStruct;
aStruct.a = someValue;
object.myStruct = aStruct
```

It is exactly the same situation as not being able to do this:

```
view.frame.size.width = aWidthValue;
```

BTW declaring a struct inside a class interface seems like a very bad style. This is much cleaner:

```
typedef struct { 
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
} customStruct;

@interface MyClass : UIView

@property (assign, nonatomic) customStruct myStruct;
```

Comment: This is not completely correct as he want to update his structure member and not set it from scratch

Comment: Thanks! When you say "Try this" are those three lines in the superView. Excuse but could you clarify a little?

Answer (score 6):

This is because `object.myStruct` returns a copy of your structure member and there is no point of changing member `a` of that copy.

You should do get the entire struct change the member and then set the struct member again (using the get/set synthesized methods)

Answer (score 2):

Define it outside/before `interface` scope:

```
struct LevelPath{
    int theme;
    int level;
};

//here goes your interface line
@interface BNGameViewController : UIViewController{
}
//create propertee here
@property (nonatomic, assign) struct LevelPath levelPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the earlier suggestions, I'd suggest to not store your struct as a property, but a member variable. E.g:

```
@interface MyClass () {

    CGPoint myPoint;

}
```

Then in your class you can assign new values to that struct directly:

```
myPoint.x = 100.0;
```

instead of when it's a @property, which is read-only:

```
myPoint = CGPointMake(100.0, myPoint.y);
```

Given that this isn't an NSObject subclass, unless you are overwriting the getter/setter methods, I don't see the purpose of making it an `@property` anymore, since that is mostly useful for ARC to help with your objects' memory management. But please correct me if I'm wrong on that point (ouch).